# agSelectCellEditor dynamic list

Tags: ag-grid

I am using ag-grid and for any given row I would like the dropdown in one column to be dependent on the value of a different column. Can I do that with agSelectCellEditor or do I have to create a custom component.

Comment: Did you find your solution? Please let us know. Did you possibly try `cellRendererFramework`?

Comment: This is exactly where I too am stuck, did you find any solution/compromise ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define your `cellEditorParams` function in a way that returns different values depending on values of another column.

Here is a sample from the ag-grid site -

```
cellEditor : 'agSelectCellEditor';
cellEditorParams: function(params) {
    var selectedCountry = params.data.country;
    if (selectedCountry==='Ireland') {
        return {
            values: ['Dublin','Cork','Galway']
        };
    } else {
        return {
            values: ['New York','Los Angeles','Chicago','Houston']
        };
    }
}
```

Take a look at this [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#example-dynamic-parameters) from official docs. You will have to replace         `agRichSelectCellEditor` with `agSelectCellEditor`

Comment: This is not a plausible solution. What if we have hundreds of row and we have render unique lists items for each row.

Comment: well thats not mentioned in the scope of the question being asked.

Comment: I think @Pratik Bhat was just demonstrating how you can use code to populate different items.  You can look at params.data.country and then make an api call...