# How to load different options in AG-Grid select dropdown ,based on other cell value in the same row with Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using the following code in the **Column Definition** :

```
 { headerName: 'Part', field: 'part', 
    cellStyle: {'background-color': 'cyan'}, editable: true, 
    cellEditor:'agSelectCellEditor', cellEditorParams:
```

I have other column in the grid ex-

```
   { headerName: 'Colour', field: 'colour', 
    cellStyle: {'background-color': 'cyan'}, editable: true, 
    cellEditor:'agSelectCellEditor', cellEditorParams: function(params) { 
    var selectedPart = params.data.type; if (selectedPart==='R&S') { 
    return { values: this.partTypeListRS }; } else if(selectedPart==='WiFi') 
    { return { values: this.partTypeListWifi }; } else 
    if(selectedPart==='Other') { return { values: this.partTypeListOther }; 
    }}},
    }
```

I am getting the error cannot read property this.partTypeListRS of undefined ,if I click on a row where selectedPart==='R&S' condition is satisfied and respectively for all the other conditions .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [agSelectCellEditor dynamic list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54712974/agselectcelleditor-dynamic-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `function(params)` ,I used the arrow function `(params)=>` , then I was able to access this inside CellEditorParams

Answer (score 2):

You can define your `cellEditorParams` function in a way that returns different values depending on values of another column.

Here is a sample from the ag-grid site -

```
cellEditor : 'agSelectCellEditor';
cellEditorParams: function(params) {
    var selectedCountry = params.data.country;
    if (selectedCountry==='Ireland') {
        return {
            values: ['Dublin','Cork','Galway']
        };
    } else {
        return {
            values: ['New York','Los Angeles','Chicago','Houston']
        };
    }
}
```

Take a look at this [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#example-dynamic-parameters) from official docs.

Comment: `cellEditor:'agSelectCellEditor', cellEditorParams: function(params) {
            var selectedPart = params.data.rs_or_wifi;
            if (selectedPart==='R&S') {
                return {
                    values: this.partTypeListRS
                };
            } else if(selectedPart==='WiFi') {
                return {
                    values: this.partTypeListWifi
                };
            }
            else if(selectedPart==='Other') {
              return {
                  values: this.partTypeListOther
              };
          }}},`

Comment: I am getting the error cannot read property this.partTypeListRS of undefined ,if I click on a row where selectedPart==='R&S' condition is satisfied  and respectively for all the other conditions